# Factorisation of a not straight-forward expression

Tags: prime-factorization

I am completely lost with this question:

*Factorise 3x <sup>2</sup>- 11x + 6*

How do you factorise this?

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint : $3x^2-11x+6=(3x^2-9x)-(2x-6)$

But this type of problem is usually solved with the cross method.

Comment: Thanks! This helped me to understand and remember how to do this kind of factorisation.

Answer (score 1):

Compute the Solutions of $$x^2-\frac{11}{3}x+2=0$$ so $$x_{1,2}=\frac{11}{6}\pm\sqrt{\frac{49}{36}}$$ this gives
$$x_{1,2}=\frac{11}{6}\pm \frac{7}{6}$$
and we get
$$x_1=3$$ or $$x_2=\frac{2}{3}$$ and we can write
$$(x-3)\left(x-\frac{2}{3}\right)=0$$

Comment: Thankyou! This helped me to check my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can do trial and error,  or use what I sort of remember as the $pqrs$ method...

For trial and error:   $3x^2$ factors as $3x\cdot x$, so, if it factors,  it's of the form $$(3x\qquad)(x\qquad)$$ ;and $6$ factors variously as $\pm6\cdot\pm1$ and $\pm3\cdot \pm2$.  You need the middle term to work out.   For instance,  $6,1$ doesn't work:  $$(3x+6)(x+1)$$ has the wrong middle term, $9x$...
There's a total of $8$ combinations to try, if you remember that order will matter.

A little experimentation leads to $\mathbf{(3x-2)(x-3)}$.

The second method goes as follows:  $(px+r)(qx+s)=pqx^2+(ps+qr)x+rs$.  Inspecting this reveals  that the $x$ term splits into $2$ terms whose coefficients have product $pqrs$, which is the product of the $x^2$ coefficient, $pq$ and the constant term, $rs$. Thus, if we start with $ax^2+bx+c$,  we can look for two numbers whose sum is $b$ and whose product is $ac$.

So, in our example,  we need two numbers (integers)  whose sum is $-11$, and whose product is $3\cdot6=18$.  We get $-2$ and $-9$.

Having found the required two numbers, we use them to split the $x$ term and proceed to factor.

$$\displaystyle 3x^2-11x+6=3x^2-2x-9x+6=x(3x-2)-3(3x-2)=(x-3)(3x-2)$$.

Note, our scratchwork above guarantees that we will always get a *common binomial factor* (in this case $(3x-2)$).

Final note:  either method will work if the quadratic polynomial is in fact factorizable over $\mathbb Z$.